# RCBD design with repeated measure data

Tags: r, repeated-measures

I am writing my thesis. I need help for statistical analysis part. 
I have spring and summer collected nitrate concentration data for 016 and 017 data. Samples are repeatedly collected from same experiment unit. I have treatment and sampling date as a fixed variables and year and block are random variables.
I will be very happy if you suggest and advice me ? I am using r programming for analysis. Your advice and suggestion will be valuable for me.